# Update CosmosDb collection with data from text file

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

A CosmosDb collection currently in use needs to be updated, and the updates have been provided via text file which will be converted into json.  The json file will not contain a key or id, only a userId to match.

The update is very minimal and one-time, probably under 1k records.

What is the best way to accomplish this?  A simple console app which utilizes a Cosmos SDK seems to be the most straightforward, but the team has limited Cosmos experience so wanted to reach out for more of a best practice solution.  Thanks in advance for any information.

Comment: Could you share the sample text file data and converted Json file?

Comment: there's really no "best" way; it's whatever way works for you. Since you tagged this as [tag:.net-core], then maybe write a c# app to go through your file, find/replace docs, etc? As written though, this is off-topic (it's a high level requirement/idea, but no code or other specific detail)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Data Migration Tool. You can get an old version of it [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-datamigrationtool/releases/tag/1.8.3).

There will be a newer version of this out early next year.